# multiprocessing pool map returning the same values for each call

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm having a problem getting different return values from a `pool.map` call. Im running this simplified example on a macbook, in a jupyter notebook with python 3.9:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

def gen_random_list(num):
    print(f"Num: {num}\n")
    ret_list = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=3).tolist()
    return ret_list
    
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    results = []
    results = pool.map(gen_random_list, range(4))
    print(results)
```

I keep getting the same list back for each call to `gen_random_list`. The complete output is this:

```
Num: 0
Num: 1
Num: 2
Num: 3




[[0, 3, 2], [0, 3, 2], [0, 3, 2], [0, 3, 2]]
```

Does anyone know why every call to `gen_random_list` is returning the same values (in this run: `[0, 3, 2]`)? And how do I fix this so I get a different random list back each time?

Thanks
Brett

Comment: The code as written does not run unless I put the multiprocessing part inside of `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Once I do that, I cannot reproduce your results, I just got `[[0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 2], [2, 4, 3], [2, 1, 0]]`.

Comment: It works as written in a jupyter notebook. The check for main, won't work in a notebook, since the notebook isn't the main process.

Comment: This is probably because the processes use the same seed to generate the numbers. Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214631/pythons-multiprocessing-pool-does-unwanted-caching?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Charchit! That was it! Subtle for sure.... Here's a working example now:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

def gen_random_list2(num):
    print(f"Num: {num}\n")
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994423/difference-between-np-random-seed-and-np-random-randomstate
    local_state = np.random.RandomState(num)
    ret_list = local_state.randint(0, 5, size=3).tolist()
    return ret_list
    
with mp.Pool(processes=processes) as pool:
    results = list(map(gen_random_list2, range(100)))
    print(results)
```